# PyTorch: cpp_extension.py:184: UserWarning: Error checking compiler version

Tags: python, windows, pytorch

## I got a problem regarding pytorch:

when i run python setup.py build_ext --inplace

I get:

...
running build_ext
C:\python36\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py:184: UserWarning: Error checking compiler version for cl: [WinError 2] Das System kann die
angegebene Datei nicht finden
warnings.warn('Error checking compiler version for {}: {}'.format(compiler, error))
building 'pointnet2._ext' extension

## SETUP:

CUDA 9.0

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin>nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Sep__1_21:08:32_Central_Daylight_Time_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.0, V9.0.176

MSVC

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin>cl
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Pytorch 1.0.1
(installed via PIP)

## Additonal:

When I run:

python setup.py install

I get:

```
...

  File "C:\python36\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
    self._build_extensions_serial()
  File "C:\python36\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 199, in build_extension
    _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
  File "C:\python36\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 558, in build_extension
    target_lang=language)
  File "C:\python36\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 717, in link_shared_object
    extra_preargs, extra_postargs, build_temp, target_lang)
  File "C:\python36\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 501, in link
    build_temp = os.path.dirname(objects[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**setup.py**

```
setup(
...  
install_requires=requirements,
    ext_modules=[
        CUDAExtension(
            name="pointnet2._ext",
            sources=_ext_sources,
            extra_compile_args={
                "cxx": ["-O2", "-I{}".format("{}/include".format(_ext_src_root))],
                "nvcc": ["-O2", "-I{}".format("{}/include".format(_ext_src_root))],
            },
        )
    ],
...
)
```

Comment: I'm getting the same kind of error ("Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden", just in English). You could try finding the line in site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py that prints this (mine is line 184), then insert these before the warnings.warn statement, so you can see where exactly torch is trying to find your compiler, then you could hack around the compiler path to make it work for you, but it will be of course just a hack and by far not the best solution:
print(compiler) ;
import traceback ;
traceback.print_exc()